# MVVM WPF How to set style on TreeViewItem based on DataType of DataContext from xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Even if some treeviewitems cannot be expanded?

so I have a treeview with these resources, but the viewmodel for one item type is hierarchical, while the other item cannot be expanded. I feel as if I should not be creating an IsExpanded property in the viewmodel of the unexpandable item, but I don't know how I would set a style for an item type based on the datatype of the content. If it's not possible to do from xaml, it is probably possible in code behind, but in that case I am probably just better off just adding an IsExpanded Property to the unexpandable item and leaving it as false

```
<DaedalusGraphViewer:MultiSelectTreeView.Resources>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type DaedalusGraphViewer:MultiSelectTreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource NameTreeViewBusItemStyle}" />
              <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                ItemsSource ="{Binding Path = bits}"
                DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:BusViewModel}" 
                >
                <Grid>
                  <Components:CenteredTextBlock
                    BorderThickness="{Binding RelativeSource ={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DaedalusGraphViewer:MultiSelectTreeView}}, Path=BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource ={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DaedalusGraphViewer:MultiSelectTreeView}}, Path=BorderBrush}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Height="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=GraphHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
                    MainText="{Binding Path = Alias}" 
                    />
                </Grid>
              </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
              <DataTemplate
                DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:BitViewModel}"
                >
                <Grid>
                  <Components:CenteredTextBlock
                    BorderThickness="{Binding RelativeSource ={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DaedalusGraphViewer:MultiSelectTreeView}}, Path=BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource ={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DaedalusGraphViewer:MultiSelectTreeView}}, Path=BorderBrush}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Height="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=GraphHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
                    MainText="{Binding Path = Alias}"
                    />
                </Grid>
              </DataTemplate>
            </DaedalusGraphViewer:MultiSelectTreeView.Resources>
```

Comment: To set a style or template based on the data type of the content, use an Implicit Style or DataTemplate. That is one defined with a `DataType` property, but no `Key` property. It will be used for all elements of the specified data type.

Comment: There is no data type property on style. I don't think I can use datatemplates for what I described, as IsExpanded is a prpoerty on the item. Datatemplates control what go into the items in the treeview, while styles determine properties on the actual treeviewitem itself. I couldn't figure out a way to bind isexpanded based off of the item itself, so I just added the IsExpanded property to all of my view models so that it will have a property to bind to.

Comment: Sorry, the property for implicit Styles is `TargetType`. Also if you're interested, I have a [blog post](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/) that contains an example of a template set both with an implicit `DataTemplate`, or with a `DataTrigger` in a Style based on a Property.